# What type of data (binary, hex...) is formatted in columns?

Tags: binary, hex, decode

I have some file formatted like this:

```
b562 1340 1800 1000 0011 df07 0811 0e27
0900 00f9 f01a 0a00 0000 0000 0000 d6bf
...
```

I'm trying to find out what it is just so I can make sense of it.

I've seen this around on other places, maybe some compiler turns code into that? could that be decoded at all?

Thanks

Comment: any type of data can be formatted into columns. there's nothing special about that... try the `od` utility, which is intended to make binary "garbage" files into semi-readable text like that.

Comment: Well, as @MarcB pointed out, this can be any type of data. One example might be the hex code which is uploaded by a programmer to a micro processor (Arduino.cc for example).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is called a hex dump, there are some services online to decode it (to some extent) like http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm